# how to declare Image as a column in Local Database in wp8 app

Tags: windows-phone-8, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I have to store the user selected image in the Local Database. When I tried to create the column as Image, its showing any datatype like Image. Only System.Windows.Controls.Image only showing

```
    private Image _imageData;
    [Column(CanBeNull = true)]
    public Image ImageData
    {
        get { return _imageData; }
        set
        {
            if (_imageData != value)
            {
                NotifyPropertyChanging("ImageData");
                _imageData = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanging("ImageData");
            }
        }
    }
```

this is the column i am trying to create in one of table. How to declare the Image as datatype?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I understood you correctly, but have you tried storing Uri instead of Image?

```
private Uri _imageUri;
[Column(CanBeNull = true)]
public Uri ImageUri
{
    get { return _imageUri; }
    set
    {
        if (_imageUri!= value)
        {
            NotifyPropertyChanging("ImageUri");
            _imageUri= value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("ImageUri");

            NotifyPropertyChanged("ImageData");
        }
    }
}

public Image ImageData
{
    get { return new BitmapImage(ImageUri); }
}
```

P.S. You're calling NotifyPropertyChanging twice, it seems like it's a typo.

Comment: Thanks Eladar. But where I have to store the actual Image? As per MSDN "You can use the binary(n), varbinary(n), or image data types to store BLOB data directly in a local database". But not able to find the data type

Comment: You can store images in isolated storage.
If you want to store BLOB, use [System.Data.Linq.Binary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.binary(v=vs.95).aspx), it maps to BLOB or IMAGE. As I know, there is a limit on BLOB size, I think it's better to use isolated storage.